# How to Retain Line Breaks From User Profile Text Fields

Tags: line-breaks

I am using `<?php the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?>` to display a user biographical info. In the users bio info box, there are physical line breaks present. Yet the results from the_author_meta() just flows the text altogether and does not recognize any line breaks.

Is there a way to have the line breaks appear as is in the user's bio box?

Comment: What are "line advances"?

Answer (score 0):

If "line advances" are line breaks you could try wrapping the output in [wpautop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: No worries, glad to help.